# How to install Wicked PDF gem in rails 3.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Right now I am using Rails 3.0.0 version. I want to install Wicked pdf gem. I don't know how to install that gem. Please tell me that step by step procedure.

Comment: rate my answer if it has helped you. cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy!

1. Add this to Gem file!

   ```
   gem 'wicked_pdf'
   gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.12.3'
   ```
2. Run **Bundle install** and run `rails generate wicked_pdf`
3. In **config/initializers/mime_types.rb** add this (or Uncomment)

   ```
   WickedPdf.config = {
        exe_path: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
   }
   ```
4. In your controller (show action)

   ```
   def show
       respond_to do |format|
           format.pdf do
             render :pdf => "file_name.pdf", :template => 'file_directory/file_name.html.erb', :encoding => 'utf-8'
           end
           format.html
   end end
   ```
5. Create a **erb.html** file and put your pdf code in it.
6. In view you have to use the route **controller#show** for your link_to tag!
7. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

use the command `gem install wicked_pdf` .See the documentation here. http://rubygems.org/gems/wicked_pdf & http://rubydoc.info/gems/wicked_pdf/0.7.9/frames

Answer (score 0):

Reminder to restart you server after changing you config/initializers/mime_types.rb  file. Other than that Afsanefda's answer worked for me.